# How to put all types in Java ArrayList and hashMap like python.(Numbers, String, List, HashMap)

Tags: java

I wanted to store all kinds of Object in an ArrayList and a HashMap in Java. Like Numbers, String, List, Map. I am having problem that how to store it. For HashMap value can be any kind of Object and I don't want to use Object class because for every object I have down cast it. I wanted to use my own custom types. The Key of HashMap will be an Integer or String. I have already search but did not get what I want. I have created one interface and some of it child classes.

```
interface JP<T> { // Interface
   T get();
}

class JI<T> implements JP<T> { // Class for contain Integer 
  T abc;
  public JI(T abc1){
    abc = abc1;
  }
  public T get(){
    return abc;
  }
}

class JS<T> implements JP<T> { // Class for contain String
  T abc1;
  public JS(T abc){
    abc1 = abc;
  }
  public T get(){
    return abc1;
 }
}

class JL<T> implements JP<T> { // Class for contain List
  List<T> abc1;
  public JL(){

  }
  public JL(List<T> abc){
      abc1 = abc;
  }
  public List<T> get(){
    return abc1;
  }
}
```

---

The problem that I am facing here is to take the return type of JL get 
method. May some one could guide me for the same. 
I don't wanted to use Object class for every data type because for 
down casting I have to check every class object reference type which 
they belongs.
Should I think more on that? or Should I use enum kind structure?
Should I think more on generics?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java is a strongly-typed language, so if you store objects of differing types in a collection or map, then you *have to* check the type and cast it before you can use the real type of the object. Now, if all the objects share a common *interface*, then you can use that, but otherwise there is no alternative.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html for an implementation of this.